# Real Analysis, Folland problem 3.5.33 Functions of Bounded Variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Problem 33 - If $F$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, then $F(b) - F(a) \geq \int_{a}^{b}F'(t)dt$.

My question: I want to know what facts arise when we know $F$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$?

There must be something within those facts that lead to this conclusion I am just lost on what would lead to this result without making a plethora of assumptions or constructing a function or something where this works out.

Also we can assume $F$ is right-continuous as well.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove this you need some background in measure theory including Fatou's lemma and the fact that a monotone increasing function is almost everywhere differentiable.

Consider the sequence of functions for $x \in [a,b],$

$$F_n(x) = n\left[F(x + 1/n)-F(x)\right].$$

This sequence is well-defined by extending $F$ with $F(x) = F(b)$ for $x > b.$

If $F$ is monotone increasing then it can be shown that the derivative $F'$ exists almost everywhere.  Furthermore, $F_n(x) \to F'(x)$ almost everywhere as $n \to \infty$ and $F'$ is measurable.

Integrating we get

$$\int_a^b F_n(x) \, dx= n \int_a^b \left[F(x + 1/n)-F(x)\right] \, dx \\ = n \int_{a + 1/n}^{b + 1/n} F(x) \, dx -n\int_{a}^{b} F(x) \, dx \\ =n \int_{b}^{b + 1/n} F(x) \, dx -n\int_{a}^{a + 1/n} F(x) \, dx \\ \leqslant F(b) - F(a).$$

Applying Fatou's lemma we get

$$\int_a^b F'(x) \, dx \leqslant  \liminf_{n \to \infty}\int_a^b F_n(x) \, dx \leqslant F(b) - F(a).$$

Comment: Small point: $n\int_b^{b+1/n}F(x)\,dx\le F(b+1/n)$ (rather than $\le F(b)$), but this is okay for the Fatou argument, because $\lim_nF(b+1/n)=F(b)$ by right continuity.

Comment: @John Dawkins: Thanks.  I worked with the restriction of $F$ to $[a,b]$ and then used a constant extension so that $F(b+1/n) = F(b)$. But your point shows I did not need this construction.

Comment: Thank you, I should have noted in the question that I am taking measure theory this is my second course in it. I should have known Fatou's lemma could be used here

Comment: @Morgan Weiss:  You're welcome.  Showing that a monotonic function is almost everywhere differentiable is not trivial, but has been discussed on this site a number of times.

Comment: If I use your approach should I show that if $F$ is monotnically increasing then $F'$ exists a.e. I am using Folland and I cannot seem to find a theorem that proves this fact. But it seems to be a well-known fact in general

Answer (score 3):

Another approach (only sketched): There is a Borel measure $\mu$, finite on compact subsets of $\Bbb R$, such that $\mu\{(a,b]\}=F(b)-F(a)$ for all real $a\le b$. Let $\mu_s+\mu_a$ be the Lebesgue decomposition of $\mu$ into singular and absolutely continuous components. The measure $\mu_a$ admits a representation $\mu_a(B)=\int_B f(x)\,dx$ for all Borel $B\subset\Bbb R$, where $f\ge 0$ is Borel measurable. In fact, $f(x) = F'(x)$ for Lebesgue a.e. $x$. Finally, $F(b)-F(a)=\mu\{(a,b]\}\ge\mu_a\{(a,b]\}=\int_a^b F'(x)\,dx$.